# Fill android layout xamarin

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-relativelayout

I got trouble with android layout in `xamarin`. How to fill space without overlapping the layout in android `xml`?

This layout confusing me. Because it's not like `php` or `xaml`. I want to make the layout view like this:

[image]

I'm using nexus 6 in design windows. When I ran the debug in emulator the view become like this:

[image]

The layout overlapping. I wonder how to fill blank space in android layout size so it can fit in my device (dynamically)?

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|bottom">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="610.3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom">
            <TextView
                android:text="Location Detail"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="199.3dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:width="100dp"
                        android:gravity="left|center|top" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="top" />
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/editTextLocationDetailName" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:width="100dp"
                        android:gravity="center|left|top" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:gravity="center|top" />
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/editTextLocationDetailAddress" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="top">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Description"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:width="100dp"
                        android:gravity="left|center|top" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:gravity="center|top" />
                    <EditText
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/editTextLocationDetailDescription" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:text="Registered User"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewLocationUser"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBarLocationDetail"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="#ff03a9f4"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="center">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there something I can do? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this xaml file & compare with your file so that you will get idea what mistake you was making

I realize the issue was using `android:gravity` (in second & third LinearLayout) along with `android:weight` which was pushing your layout toward top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="610.3dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Location Detail"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="199.3dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <TextView
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:width="100dp"
                android:gravity="left|center|top" />
            <TextView
                android:text=":"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="top" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editTextLocationDetailName" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:text="Address"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:width="100dp"
                android:gravity="center|left|top" />
            <TextView
                android:text=":"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:gravity="center|top" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editTextLocationDetailAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="top">
            <TextView
                android:text="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:width="100dp"
                android:gravity="left|center|top" />
            <TextView
                android:text=":"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:gravity="center|top" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editTextLocationDetailDescription" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="Registered User"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewLocationUser"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLocationDetail"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="#ff03a9f4"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for this. I just added image viewer at bottom to fill the layout :)